# counting cells with COUNTA with a query on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

i want to count the number of range on my sheet, but i want to make it without the cells that contain a specific word, for now I'm using this syntax to count in general but it's not the final results that i want
**=TO_TEXT(COUNTIF(K8:K,"COMMANDE CONFIRMER")) & " Commandes confirmer"**
this specific word that i want to be check on it it's on cell L
thank you in advance

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can count the cells that contain a specific word by

```
=COUNTIF(K8:K,"*myWord*")
```

and therefore subtract this value from the overall count